# Automating Aggregating Data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 100+ rows that are updated daily and as of now I have to update my last column manually. In my last column "Key Results Aggerated" I have to manually copy and paste Key Results into single cells per employee. I spent hours trying to figure out a solution but I am unable to. I have tried using import range function and concatenate function but I am having a hard time automating it since users can always add/remove a new row for "Key Result" at any time of the day. Thanks in advance.

[Pic: Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpY0L.png)

[Pic: Results I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgUCO.png)

[Google Spreadsheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sBZN3vrM1r8iiVHFz5FdTUQKdMUe7_1NNipJBjiayn4/edit#gid=0)

Comment: If you're using app-script, you could get the values (*at column D*) on the range that starts from the email and ends onec the other email is reached, then, join the values obtained at the range in a single string with line breaks. It would be interesting to see how it can be done with fomula-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may insert this in E1 and protect that row:

```
={"KEYS";MAP(A2:A,D2:D,LAMBDA(aval,dval,IF(aval="","", TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,dval:INDEX(D:D,ROW(dval)+IFNA(XMATCH("*",INDEX(A:A,ROW(aval)+1):INDEX(A:A, ROWS(D:D))),ROWS(A:A))-1)))))}
```

Erase previously all the prior formulas in E. Let me know

Comment: This is really strange. I tried the formula you provided 2 days ago and it worked perfectly fine. Today, I gave it a try and the formula is now aggregating wrong info. In column E, it is aggerating data from other rows. I attempted to fix it but I'm still having issues. By any chance do you know why? Thanks, in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xf4NgGTJOQPVJzibJ_RNztA13ddS-nMJleQ5G8fOEVM/edit#gid=0